# Heroku custom domain name comes up blank

Tags: heroku

I found this site through the Heroku help link.

My app launches on heroku address... [secret-brushlands](https://secret-brushlands-43080.herokuapp.com/)

but when I pointed my domain from my old host to where the app is on heroku I get [a heroku page](http://www.hypochondriacmd.com/) that just says nothing is here.

I followed the Heroku documents and pointed my DNS to the xxx.herokudns.com link they gave me on the settings page. The fact that i come up with a heroku page at all and not my previous placeholder wordpress page i had at that domaine name before tells me it is redirecting.

Any idea why my app is not at the address they told me to direct the name to?